Instance spaces - donut hypothesis
I am working on an assignment that specifies an origin-centered donut hypothesis in an instance space. The formula is as follows:
$$
h \leftarrow \Bigl\langle a < \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < b \Bigr\rangle, 
$$
where $a < b$.
This would result in $2$ origin-centered circles drawn on the instance space, with the instance at $(x, y)$ being contained in the resulting "donut". The $a$ value would refer to the point where the inner circle intersects the instance space, and the $b$ value would refer to the point where the outer circle intersects the instance space.
An example would be hypothesis $h \leftarrow \langle 5, 9 \rangle$, which means the inner circle intersects at point $5$ and the outer circle intersects at point $9$.
I have to come up with a different shape. I have decided on origin-centered oval donuts. So we still have $2$ circles, but this will obviously require $4$ input values ($a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$) as we are not working with perfect circles, but rather with ovals.
My issue is that I can't come up with the formula for the oval donut hypothesis. Can anyone please help?

this other page has 20000   questions on machine learning  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning
